# How to expose factory for value objects to QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to make value objects without default constructors and setters, that can be created from QML. I came to implementation of Factory as workaround, that will be passed like a singleton to QML. But when I tried to use it I get "Error: Unknown method return type: Point" and when I closing application crash happening with "free(): invalid pointer" message in logs.

Point.h:

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

#include <QObject>

struct Point
{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(int x READ getX CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(int y READ getY CONSTANT)

public:
    Point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {

    }

    Point(const Point& that) = default;
    Point& operator=(const Point& that) = default;

    int getX() {
        return this->x;
    }

    int getY() {
        return this->y;
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE QString getCoordinates() {
        return QString("x=%1; y=%2").arg(this->x, this->y);
    }

private:
    int x;
    int y;
};

#endif // POINT_H
```

Factory.h:

```
#ifndef FACTORY_H
#define FACTORY_H

#include <QObject>

#include "point.h"

class Factory : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(Factory)

public:
    static Factory* instance() {
        static Factory factory;
        return &factory;
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE Point newPoint(int x, int y) {
        return Point(x, y);
    }

private:
    Factory() {

    }
};

#endif // FACTORY_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QObject>

#include "factory.h"
#include "point.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterUncreatableType<Point>("test", 1, 0, "Point", "error: no default constructor");
    qmlRegisterSingletonType<Factory>("test", 1, 0, "Factory",
                                      [](QQmlEngine* engine, QJSEngine* scriptEngine) -> QObject* {
        Q_UNUSED(engine)
        Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)

        return Factory::instance();
    });

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

import test 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var point = Factory.newPoint(5, 10);
        console.log("completed")
    }
}
```

Comment: This example doesn't compile: 
`factory.h:19: error: could not convert ‘Point(x, y)’ from ‘Point’ to ‘QVariant’`

Comment: @ju_ My excuses, it was returning a Point.

Comment: The error "Error: Unknown method return type: Point" can be fixed by the following action.
You need to add `Point() {}` in the *point.h* and replace     `qmlRegisterUncreatableType<Point>("test", 1, 0, "Point", "error: no default constructor");` with `qRegisterMetaType<Point>();` in the *main.cpp*.

Comment: The "free(): invalid pointer" crash is caused by the your implementation of Factory. I changed it with the example provided by Qt (http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType-1) and there is no crash anymore.

Comment: @ju_ Problem was in ownership - it belong to QML by default. I forgot to call:
        Factory* factory = Factory::instance();
        engine->setObjectOwnership(factory, QQmlEngine::ObjectOwnership::CppOwnership);

Comment: @ju_ Approach with qRegisterMetaType is contrary to what I want. Idea in implementation value objects without default public constructor.